# how to update specific user ? update.php

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml, xampp, visual-web-developer

Below is my update.php code. However, I am seeking for code to update specific user. For example

Search Id: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** [search]

If the user wants to search id details for id : 11

Then update.php will show open a page that can update that 11 details.

For my code, it is not specific.

Hope someone can help me please.

**update.php**

```
<center>
<h1><u>Library Database</u></h1>
</center>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("c_database",$con);
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery="UPDATE myaduan SET id='$_POST[id]', nama_pengadu='$_POST[nama_pengadu]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery,$con);
};
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$DeleteQuery="DELETE FROM myaduan WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($DeleteQuery,$con);
};
$sql="SELECT * FROM myaduan";
$myEdit=mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "<table style=border:1px solid silver cellpadding=5px cellspacing=0px align=center border=0>
<tr>
<td colspan=4 style=background:0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; fontsize: 20px>UPDATE RECORD</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>ISBN</td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myEdit)){
echo "<form action=update.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=id value=".$record['id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=nama_pengadu value=".$record['nama_pengadu']. " </td>";
echo "<td>". "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=".$record['id']. " </td>";
echo "<td>"."<input type=submit name=update value=update"." </td>";
echo "<td>"."<input type=submit name=delete value=delete"." </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo"</form>";
}
echo"</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should stop using mysql_connect . It was deprecated , instead use another one such as PDO.
You can run a query to display all your users then have tow links in front of each one like:
-User1 **update** **delete**
-User2 **update** **delete** 
.
.
.
if u hit delete you post all your info to ur processing page and delete the user .If you hit update you load a form to another div using Jquery/ajax or you redirect to another page with your form on it and you update your user info .
This way you ll have a cleaner/user freindly area to do your thing .